# how to translate this bashrc code to suse 11 commands

Tags: environment-variables, tcsh, suse, matlab

I am trying to link MATLAB with Cadence Virtuoso (an electrical engineering software) in SUSE Linux 11, and I have manual PDF that is the guide to do so. My problem is that the commands that are given in the manual are not compatible with Linux SUSE.

Does anyone know how to translate the following commands to SUSE compatible commands?

```bsh
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH `cds_root spectre`/tools/dfII/lib:`cds_root spectre`/tools/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
setenv MATLABPATH `cds_root spectre`/tools/spectre/matlab:${MATLABPATH}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The commands you show are specific to the `csh` and `tcsh` shells, not to any Linux distribution in particular.

The commands set two environment variables, and in a standard POSIX `sh` shell, such as `bash`, but also `zsh` and, e.g., `yash`, these two commands would be written as

```bsh
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$(cds_root spectre)/tools/dfII/lib:$(cds_root spectre)/tools/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export MATLABPATH="$(cds_root spectre)/tools/spectre/matlab:$MATLABPATH"
```

You could write this neater by only executing `cds_root spectre` once like so:

```bsh
cds_tools=$(cds_root spectre)/tools
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$cds_tools/dfII/lib:$cds_tools/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export MATLABPATH="$cds_tools/spectre/matlab:$MATLABPATH"
unset -v cds_tools
```

So, to reiterate, the commands are specific to a *shell* (or type of shell, [the C-shells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_shell)), not to a particular distribution of an operating system.  The guide or manual you are reading is a bit older and written for a system where `csh` or `tcsh` was the default interactive shell (possibly a BSD-derived system). You can use these shells on any Unix today, but if you want to convert the command to be usable in any modern POSIX-compatible shell, then the commands I've given above are the ones you are most likely to want to use.